# Docker is too fast to start containers on reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd

I am running a compose file with `restart: always` on some services, with the following content and an `.env` file.

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  <some_name>:
    image: ${IMAGE}
    restart: always
    container_name: <some_name>
    volumes:
      - "${VOLUMES}"
    ports:
      - "${EXTERNAL_IP}:8089:${HOME_PORT}"
    command: <some_command>
```

However, the containers don't come up upon rebooting the host.

From the journal I see,

```
<date> <user> systemd[1]: Starting docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine...
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=info msg="Starting up"
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 8089-8089: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 <IP>:8089: bind: cannot assign requested address"
<date> <user> dockerd[830]: time="<some_time>" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=<some_sha> error="driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint <container_name> (<some_sha>): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 <IP>:8089: bind: cannot assign requested address"
```

However, when I can ssh in and issue `docker compose up -d`, the containers start. This makes me think that docker should just wait a little.

OS: `Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)`

Kernel: `6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.73-1+rpt1 (2024-01-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Docker version `25.0.4, build 1a576c5`

Docker Compose version `v2.24.7`

How can I make docker wait a little upon reboots? Any other ideas? I didn't find a github issue, is this well known?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I have this in the docker.service systemd unit file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service time-set.target
Wants=network-online.target containerd.service
Requires=docker.socket
```

In my case the network is managed by NetworkManager. The `network-online.target` is hooked to NetworkManager.

```bash
$ systemctl is-enabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
enabled
disabled
```

Apparently though docker and other programs don't wait for `network-online.target` or `network-online.target` completes prematurely.

I still have no solution.

**Workaround:** Remove the IP from port publishing, like

```yaml
ports:
      - "8089:${HOME_PORT}"
```

Limitations: Only viable if the host has a single IP or if you don't care which IP the service will take.

**Ugly hack:**

Add a systemd unit as described on [systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE](https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/#faq)

```ini
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
After=nss-lookup.target
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=sh -c 'until ping -c 1 example.com; do sleep 1; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

Comment: Is your workaround working for you?? Do your containers start automatically after the host reboots??